# $f$ is differentiable. If $\lim_{x \to c}f'(x)$ exists, then this limit must be $f'(c)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

**Please prove:** Let $f:(a,b) \to R$ be differentiable function, and let $c \in (a,b).  $  If $\lim_{x \to c}f'(x)$ exists and is finite, then this limit must be $f'(c)$.

I tried doing it directly but it doesn't quite work out. I experimented on some common functions (like $\sin(x), x^2$) and it seems pretty obvious.

I'm thinking about using contradiction, although after writing down some definitions, I couldn't proceed. Or, probably if I could show that $f'(x)$ is continuous, then I win. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: $f'$ may not always be continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: By the mean value theorem, there exists a $c_h \in (x, x + h)$ such that

$$\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} = f'(c_h)$$

Comment: Oh! Actually is there a way without using MVT? We haven't talked about it yet.

Comment: To be pedantic, you need to include $h$ negative, so you have to say $c_h\in(x-|h|,x+|h|)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Indeed that's true - I just wanted to give a brief hint answer that can easily be expanded to a full proof.

Comment: @Misakov I'd have to think about it for a little bit; the MVT approach is what first came to mind. What tools do you have available?

Comment: @user61527 This is my first undergraduate analysis course. We just finished differentiation (like definition and chain rule). Actually we're gonna talk about MVT next class, so probably I was just too hurried :p

Comment: That's interesting. I actually managed to prove it using intermediate value theorem for derivatives...mind explain how you would proceed using mean value theorem?

Comment: @Misakov Just take limits as $h \to 0$; by the squeeze theorem, $c_h \to c$. The left side is then $f'(c)$, while the right side is $\lim_{x \to c} f'(x)$.